# How to write a sql query if order time is greater then 24:00:00 than 1 otherwise 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Order Time
00:36:06
02:21:59
04:53:57
05:52:38
00:29:11
17:53:29
00:17:03
02:03:20
01:24:02
00:09:43
00:20:55
02:53:30
00:32:26
07:45:31
09:11:37
00:19:17
92:11:21
00:19:08
00:10:50
02:46:05
```

How to write a sql query if order time is greater then 24:00:00 than 1 otherwise 0?

Comment: What type is this column?

Comment: @Mureinik Type is Time

Comment: How can this row `92:11:21` be `DateTime `

Comment: This is a hint to get you thinking ...   SELECT  OrderID , OrderDateTime , DATEDIFF(HOUR,OrderDateTime,GETDATE()) as HoursAgo FROM MyOrdersTable  WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,OrderDateTime,GETDATE()) >= 24

Comment: @D-Shih He wrote Time not Datetime. If your problem is with hours of a day, you can also store durations.

Comment: Hmm... From ["time (Transact-SQL)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "Defines a time of a day. The time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.". Last time I checked, my days didn't have 92 hours... @Javatasse

Comment: @stickybit I am not saying it is a good idea to store durations that way, but it looks like it is possible on SQL Server or the OP is wrong about the database he is using or the field type or he is asking about a scenario that is not possible. I assume though he knows what he is talking about. There are other databases as well where you can store other times about 24:00:00. In MySQL you can store values up to hour 838.

Comment: @Javatasse: And I'm not saying it was a bad way, if it was possible. ;) The documentation and a quick test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23833) however, makes me believe it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `ordertime` is a string.  You can do this as:

```
select (case when ordertime > '24:00:00' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: But if 92 hour values are possible, then it isn't a stretch to see 100 hour values. So string comparison is risky.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in some magic way you were able to insert 92:11:21 into a time column, use this calculated column in your query:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second, 0, [Order Time]) > 86400 
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
  END AS GreaterThan24h
```